# Why is there a minimum amount of ADA required to vote for Project Catalyst proposals?

Tags: catalyst

Voting on Project Catalyst proposals currently requires a wallet with 500 ADA or more.
It has been stated in Catalyst Town hall meetings that it is unlikely to be lowered significantly below that figure.

What are the barriers to lowering it further? 
At what point does the cost of registering to vote exceed the voting rewards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Dor Garbash mentioned there are several reasons:

- performance - the reason why they delayed Fund4 is that now the engineering team is working to improve the overall processes so that more people can participate
- fraud - to prevent people who don't want to invest time and resources of the project but want to harm the community. So if this barrier is low more scammers/spammers can participate which will lead to lower quality of the whole ecosystem
- meaningful participation - this point is connected with the previous one: people who are interested in the development of Cardano and can add value to Cardano should participate